# How do I create a score based on two or more weighted parameters?

Tags: leaderboards, ranking

In my game I have two variables `x` and `y` which should be "included" in the final score, but with different "weights" (unknown and possibly different), so I need some function `f(x, y)` with an output in the `0<=f(x, y)<=inf` interval.

There are some constraints on x and y:

```
1<=x<=60
1<=y<=9999
```

What is the best way to combine these two values to actually look nice?

Generally, what is the best way to combine different number of variables with different constraints without them "overlapping"?

Comment: What do you mean by "looking nice" and "overlapping"? When I hear "weighted parameters", I think of multiplying each value by its associated weight and summing the results. Is that something like you're thinking of?

Comment: @Anko, about overlapping: assume that we have x=21 and y=19. I had formula like: x*y + x. What we have now is 19*21 + 21 = 420. And now take x=20 and y=20: 20*20 + 20 = 420. So, choosing weights is also a big question... how to choose them?

Comment: So you want every score to be unique? If so, what about y*60 + x. But that isn't looking nice because it will result in y being very important and x being far less important (in fact, you can always take the y value and only if it is different, you have to look at the x value)

Comment: @jalgames, yes, I want each score to be unique and also variable x should be more important than y, but also I want to make values in an interval like [0, inf] and not [big_value, inf].

Comment: What about x + y / 9999? You won't get a range to inf if you have these upper limits.

Comment: @jalgames, if we'll take y/9999 than small values will be too small: 2/9999 = 0.0002 and to show them in Game Center it's not quite good or right, 'cause it will be difficult to compare them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that your inputs are integers. Then since we have only a finite set of outputs, we can map them to an integer ranking in order of least to greatest, as I'll do here. You can remap them to an arbitrary curve from there if you prefer.

Geometrically, you're looking for a curve in a 2D grid that goes from the point (1, 1) to (60, 9999), visiting every integer point within the rectangle with those corners exactly once.

You can then use this to associate every such (x,y) with a unique integer score in the range [1, 599940]. (ie. a [bijection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection), as is necessary for your "no overlap" criterion)

You also want to ensure that if (x2, y2) has a greater score than (x1, y1), then either x2 > x1 or y2 > y1. (ie. a higher score must strictly dominate a lower score on at least one axis)

[image: some sample curves for a smaller 6x9 problem]

The most straightforward way to do this (given your desire to make x more important than y) is to scan up each column to the top (y = 9999), then zig-zag back down to the start of the next column (y = 1). That yields the function:

score = 9999 * x + y - 9999

Testing out a few values: (1, 1) => 1, (1, 2) => 2, (1, 9999) => 9999, (2, 1) => 10000, (60, 9999) => 599940.

If you want a pattern that keeps x & y more balanced in their importance, you could try using a [Z-order curve like Morton Ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order_curve), but the way this jumps around will be very difficult for players to understand, and it may appear to them that their score is being assigned randomly. Increasing x or y will always yield a greater score from such a curve, but which one gives a bigger increase will vary. Increasing your y by 1 may increase your score by 5 in one place, and by 100 in another.

**A different approach:**

If we don't care about densely filling our score space (ie. there can be gaps between two valid scores, where no combination of inputs will give an intermediate score), we can think about this as a linear combination with specially-chosen weights:

score = xWeight * x + yWeight * y + zWeight * z - (xWeight * xMin + yWeight * yMin + zWeight * zMin)

The weights have to be in particular ratios to avoid collisions though. The only way I know how to find them is by exhaustive search. There's probably better ways, but here's a clumsy example:

```
for(xWeight = 1; xWeight < maxWeight; xWeight++)
{
   for(yWeight = 1; yWeight < xWeight; yWeight++)
   {
       if(CheckWeights(xWeight, yWeight))
          validWeights.Add(xWeight, yWeight);
   }
}

bool CheckWeights(int xWeight, int yWeight)
{
   for(x = 1; x < xMax; x++)
   {
       // Is there any collision between this multiple of x and a multiple of y?
       if(x * xWeight % yWeight == 0 && x*xWeight/yWeight < yMax)
         return false;
   }
   return true;
}
```

This gives you lots of choices of weights, but getting close to particular ratios usually requires making the weights (and search space) fairly large. For instance, with weights under 100 we can get an xWeight:yWeight ratio as low as 1.010204 (99, 98), or as high as 1.622951 (99, 61) (assuming the xWeight is to be strictly larger than yWeight)

To extend this beyond two variables, find weights you like for the first two. Then generate all scores that can be formed using those variables and those weights. Next, repeat, finding a weight for the next variable and a weight for the score-so-far (in this search, the for loop over the domain of x would instead loop over the domain of valid scores from the previous step). You can repeat until you run out of variables or your search space becomes too impractical.

In terms of the geometric analogy, this method corresponds most closely to the second drawing, with the diagonal zig-zag. Choosing different weights is analogous to tilting the zig-zag to be steeper or shallower.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer is great! But what about selecting weights for each variable according to their "contribution"? For instance I have x, y, z. X ([1; 60]), Y ([1; 9999]), Z ([1; 5000]) and their weights should follow this P(X) > P(Y) > P(Z), where P function = priority function. Could I just set weights as 0.50 > 0.30 > 0.20 as multipliers for X, Y, Z variables?

Comment: You don't have 100% free choice of your weights, given that you want to avoid collisions. For the x,y case you describe, the smallest weights I can find that work are [score = 84 * x + 67 * y - 151]. I'll expand on this above.

Comment: I've expanded on the answer above with a method to find non-colliding weights.